# Twitter Api 1.1 response as {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

Tags: php, twitter

I want to Integrate Twitter users time line in my web page. for that i am using following lib TwitterAPIExchange.php  ( https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php )

in the index.php file , I have provided all the required keys properly.

Wherever I try to run Index.php, I get {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]} error and i am not able to figure out how to solve it.

i am using get method to fetch data.

here is the index.php code :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
'consumer_key' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
'consumer_secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
);


/** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=fresherworld';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not seeing anything wrong in your code. but try to check some thing.
1) check your twitter app permission, set it to read, write,
2) try to regenerate your consumer key/secret.
3) does user has approved your app, you can see only those user details who has approved your app.
4) use latest lib.